# Teradata - Cannot nest aggregate operations with case

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I am trying to run the following query:

```
select BI_NROCTA,
MAX(CASE WHEN FECHA_REGISTRO='2019-12-01' THEN COUNT(TRAMO) ELSE 0 END) "2019-12-01",
MAX(CASE WHEN FECHA_REGISTRO='2019-12-02' THEN COUNT(TRAMO) ELSE 0 END) "2019-12-02",
MAX(CASE WHEN FECHA_REGISTRO='2019-12-03' THEN COUNT(TRAMO) ELSE 0 END) "2019-12-03"

from DL_RG_ANALYTICS.SH_MORA_OSC_2 
WHERE BI_NROCTA='0004890702108691953'
GROUP BY BI_NROCTA,TRAMO,FECHA_REGISTRO
```

But the query error:
Cannot nest aggregate operations.

Should I use another query type?

Comment: You should explain the logic you want to accomplish.  And provide sample data and desired rseults.

Comment: As Gordon wrote: What exactly do you want to calculate, your GROUP BY is confusing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
select
BI_NROCTA,
max("2019-12-01"),
...
from
(
select
BI_NROCTA,
count (CASE WHEN FECHA_REGISTRO='2019-12-01' THEN (TRAMO) ELSE null END) as "2019-12-01",
...
from DL_RG_ANALYTICS.SH_MORA_OSC_2 
WHERE BI_NROCTA='0004890702108691953'
GROUP BY BI_NROCTA --other group by columns not needed
) t
group by
BI_NROCTA
```

Comment: Thanks! very useful

Comment: If this is what you're after, note that the outer query is not needed. The inner query already does `group by BI_NROCTA`.

Comment: The OP's original query didn't make a lot of sense, I was just trying to show how to do the two aggregates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you want conditional aggregation like this:

```
select BI_NROCTA, TRAMO,
       SUM(CASE WHEN FECHA_REGISTRO = '2019-12-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "2019-12-01",
       SUM(CASE WHEN FECHA_REGISTRO = '2019-12-02' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "2019-12-02",
       SUM(CASE WHEN FECHA_REGISTRO = '2019-12-03' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "2019-12-03"
from DL_RG_ANALYTICS.SH_MORA_OSC_2 
WHERE BI_NROCTA = '0004890702108691953'
GROUP BY BI_NROCTA, TRAMO;
```

This counts the records on each date.

Comment: You are right but instead of "then 1" I need to count "tramo" per day

Comment: And If I change "then 1" to "then count(tramo)" It give the same error of 'Cannot nest aggregate operations'

Comment: The column tramo has 3 ranges, that's why I need to put "tramo" and not just 1 :/

Comment: Then you probably need a derived table to do the counts, then the sum in an outer query, although I'm not sure I understand your goal.

Comment: @Sebastián . . . Put `tramo` into the `group by`, so the counts are on separate rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff like this?

select BI_NROCTA,
       SUM(CASE WHEN FECHA_REGISTRO = '2019-12-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "2019-12-01",
       SUM(CASE WHEN FECHA_REGISTRO = '2019-12-02' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "2019-12-02"

from DL_RG_ANALYTICS.SH_MORA_OSC_2 
WHERE BI_NROCTA = '0004890702108691953'
GROUP BY BI_NROCTA, TRAMO;

Comment: @Andrew how it would be? do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get the counts by date (`FECHA_REGISTRO`), you can do something like this:

```sql
select FECHA_REGISTRO, COUNT(TRAMO)
from DL_RG_ANALYTICS.SH_MORA_OSC_2 
where BI_NROCTA='0004890702108691953'
and FECHA_REGISTRO in ('2019-12-01','2019-12-02','2019-12-03')
group by FECHA_REGISTRO
```

I took out `BI_NROCTA` from the `group by` since you're only looking at one value in your `where` clause.

**Updated**
This will get the results for the different values of `TRAMO`:

```sql
select FECHA_REGISTRO, TRAMO, COUNT(*)
from DL_RG_ANALYTICS.SH_MORA_OSC_2 
where BI_NROCTA='0004890702108691953'
and FECHA_REGISTRO in ('2019-12-01','2019-12-02','2019-12-03')
group by FECHA_REGISTRO, TRAMO
```

Comment: And if I want to show per "tramo" tramo has 3 different sections?

Comment: No problem, just add the extra field to your `select` and `group by`.  See updated answer above.